# How can @Configuration class is loaded while @ComponentScan is not annotated for the same class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

I come across this [**tutorial**](https://zetcode.com/spring/embeddeddatabasebuilder/) which shows how to use the *H2* embedded database in
spring application and it is working fine without any issue.

However by checking the code I did not understand how can the configuration class `DBConfig`
is being discovered and treated as configuration class for the ApplicationContext so can the beans inside be created.

Please note that it is not used as argument in `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext()` and `@ComponentScan` and `@Configuration` are not annotated in the same class.

As you can see below for the class `Application`

```java
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.zetcode")
public class Application {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // the application context is taking as argument the same Class
        var ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Application.class);
        var app = ctx.getBean(Application.class);

        app.run();

        ctx.close();
    }

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    private void run() {

        var sql = "SELECT * FROM cars";

        var cars = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Car.class));

        cars.forEach(car -> logger.info("{}", car));
    }
}
```

and class `DBConfig`

```java
@Configuration
public class DBConfig  {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        var builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        var db = builder
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2) // HSQL or DERBY
                .addScript("db/schema.sql")
                .addScript("db/data.sql")
                .build();
        return db;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate createJdbcTeamplate() {

        var template = new JdbcTemplate();
        template.setDataSource(dataSource());

        return template;
    }
}
```

I also did some JUnit Tests and I found that the `DBConfig` was created and so the Beans defined inside it.

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=Application.class)
public class EmbeddedTest {
    
    
    @Autowired
    private DBConfig dbConfig;
    
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertNotNull(dbConfig);
        assertNotNull(dataSource);
    }

}
```

Comment: `basePackages = "com.zetcode"`?

Comment: Kindly check the link in the Tutorial to see the structure of the project !

Comment: The entire question should be in the … question.

Comment: Looked. See previous comment - your config is in a sub-package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do some **debugging** in order to figure out how spring works for the above case.

As we did not provide the Configured Class to our Application context, Spring will use the `@ComponentScan` to fetch it. **How ?** via the package `com.zetcode` provided in the annotation. It scans the package and all subpackages under `com.zetcode` searching for classes:

```
src    
├───main
│   ├───java
│   │   └───com
│   │       └───zetcode
│   │           │   Application.java
│   │           ├───config
│   │           │       DBConfig.java
│   │           └───model
│   │                   Car.java
│   └───resources
│       │   logback.xml
│       └───db
│               create-db.sql
│               insert-data.sql
└───test
    └───java
```

Thus, it will finds 3 : `Application`, `DBConfig`, `Car` and for each one it sees if it is a candidate components. In our Example, the generic Beans are `Application` `DBConfig` only. Once they are identified, the next step was to check the `@Bean` Method. And for each one identified it will create the dedicated Bean. Finally it will do the autowiring.